# Alternative to xpath with regex

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have some html pages with different phone numbers on it.
Example:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">(xxx) xxxx xxxx</p>
<span style="text-align: center;">xxxxxxxxxx</span>
<li style="text-align: center;">(xxx) x xxx xxxx</li>
<p style="text-align: left;">xxxxx xxxx</p>
```

I would like to know the best way to change or even remove them using php.

My main idea would be using xpath with regex to find the text, but I believe regex doesn't work with xpath.

Comment: Doing something with HTML, better to use xpath instead of regex. Just use Chrome Inspect tool to copy the xpath location of the HTML element u want to add or remove

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XPATH but i find a nice article that can help you to [Use PHP Functions in XPath Expressions](https://cowburn.info/2009/10/23/php-funcs-xpath/).

You need to create a function that she do stuff : **preg_match_all** or **preg_match** or **preg_replace**.

after write you variable which contains html code :

```
$YourHtmlCode = <<<HTML
'<p style="text-align: center;">(xxx) xxxx xxxx</p>
    <span style="text-align: center;">xxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <li style="text-align: center;">(xxx) x xxx xxxx</li>
    <p style="text-align: left;">xxxxx xxxx</p>';
HTML;
```

Convert your html text to DOM Document like :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($YourHtmlCode, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

After use registerPHPFunctions to call the function as above.

---

I use **(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<)** to match all elements between **>** and **<** operator.  [Example](https://regex101.com/r/KW7QUj/1)

You can do like this to get all parts.

```
<?php
 
$reg = '/(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\<)/m';
$str = '<p style="text-align: center;">(xxx) xxxx xxxx</p>
<span style="text-align: center;">xxxxxxxxxx</span>
<li style="text-align: center;">(xxx) x xxx xxxx</li>
<p style="text-align: left;">xxxxx xxxx</p>';

preg_match_all($reg, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
}

?>
```

After you can do your modification in the value directly.

If you want to replace directly the value with regex, you can use **preg_replace**.

For example :

```
<?php
$reg = '/(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\<)/m';
$str = '<p style="text-align: center;">(xxx) xxxx xxxx</p>
<span style="text-align: center;">xxxxxxxxxx</span>
<li style="text-align: center;">(xxx) x xxx xxxx</li>
<p style="text-align: left;">xxxxx xxxx</p>';

echo preg_replace($reg, "ReplaceString", $str); 
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

An example using regular expressions. The surrounding tags are also removed.

```
((\+|\d|\(|(<.*?>))[\d\-\(\)\. ]{9,}(\.|\n| |<\/.*>)(?!(png|jpg|<)))
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/nqWXDM/1)

Comment: Please read [answer]. Refrain from adding code-only answers, as they may be difficult to understand. Instead, [edit] the answer to explain *why* this code solves the problem at hand, either in text around, or comments within the code.